# Adding tooltip to image from PHP

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

So i followed this example: http://www.ehow.com/how_10010263_put-php-code-tooltip.html
And i'm building a jqgrid where in one column i have images with title which i want to be tooltips(because image title disapper after some time in some browsers). So in php i use that to install image:

```
 $image = "<div id='tooltip'>
               <img height='16' width='16' title='$image_title' 
               src='". base_url()."img/icons/Blue/Bubble5.png'>
           </div>";
```

Then i try to do that in jquery:

```
$("#tooltip img[title]").tooltip();
```

However there is no effect.

Any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Edit:
That is how one cell with image looks in jqgrid:

```
<div id="tooltip">
    <img width="16" height="16" src="path/img/icon/Blue/Bubble5.png" title="random test">
</div>
```

Can there be problem because i have like 20 rows with same content only title is different.

My imports:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/i18n/grid.locale-si.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/leadFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/sorttable.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/switcherFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: if you inspect the element does your image title have text in it?

Comment: Did you include JQuery & JQuery UI? Because [`tooltip`](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) needs JQueryUI.

Comment: yes they do, and on mouse over it's shown but only as title not tooltip.

Comment: I have included, because if i wouldn't have i would see error in console. However: <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Then we have not enough code to help you. Try to create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (after parsing php) or paste more code to your question.

Comment: I just pasted some, i don't know what else relevant to that problem, tell me what u need and u get it.

Comment: Hm i just moved my code $("#tooltip img[title]").tooltip(); to document ready and now i get tooltip is not a function.

Comment: Open your `jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js` file and search after `_tooltip:`. If you find such a string, tooltip is integratet, if not, go to [JQuery UI download page](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!) and load the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the image is the only thing in the `<div>` I would suggest you try adding a class to the `<img>` tag(s).

```
<img class="TT" height='16' width='16' title='$image_title' 
           src='". base_url()."img/icons/Blue/Bubble5.png'>
```

then you can use

```
$(".TT").tooltip();
```

This way every image tag with this class will have the tooltip applied and use the title by default.

if you prefer a simple approach, the example at [jqueryUI example](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#entry-examples) page shows that you can just do

```
$(document).tooltip();
```

then every item on the page with a title will have a tooltip associated with it.

EDIT: after you update your version it is possible that your initial solution will work.

Comment: I guess i'm having problem with missing includes, i printed all in edit is there somthing missing?

Comment: hold up, wait a minute, you are using jqueryui 1.7.something.  was the tooltip widget in that version?

Comment: yeh according to http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip it was included in 1.9.  upgrade.  also, dont forget to update jquery at the same time.

Comment: Ow so my bad again :S Tenx for help!

Answer (score 0):

You must use `foreach`:

```
$("#tooltip").foreach(function(){
 $(this).find("img[title]").tooltip();
});
```

if you have multiple divs with id tooltip or

```
$("#tooltip").find("img[title]").foreach(function(){
 $(this).tooltip();
});
```

if you have multiple imgs in one `div#tooltip`.

Comment: Tenx for that input too, but i'm having problem from start with using wrong vesrion of jquery, however will also use that!

Comment: while using `foreach` is possible, it is not a `MUST` and perhaps not the most efficient way to accomplish this.